# In Azure DevOps REST Api how to get the build variables of the given build?

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

Using the REST API I can easily obtain an object corresponding to the given build. But at the time when that build was queued it was given build variables. Some were set at queue time, some were inherited from the build definition.

So far I failed to figure out how I can assess these build variables. The build object does not seem to contain them.

I can clearly see the top level template parameters in the `parameters` property. But where are the build variables?

**Edit 1**

We use the on-prem version of Azure DevOps 2020. The highest api version it supports is `6.1-preview` and the "[Runs - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)" in that version does not seem to return much. Please, observe:

```
C:\> Invoke-RestMethod "$TfsInstanceUrl/DFDevOps/_apis/pipelines/$($b.definition.id)/runs/$($b.id)?api-version=6.1-preview" -UseDefaultCredentials


_links       : @{self=; web=; pipeline.web=; pipeline=}
pipeline     : @{url=https://tdc1tfsapp01.dayforce.com/tfs/DefaultCollection/d85566a3-9e95-4891-9fd8-42750a0bc250/_apis/pipelines/8781?revision=19; id=8781; revision=19;
               name=PRBuild Stress Test; folder=\}
state        : completed
result       : succeeded
createdDate  : 2022-02-11T15:57:07.4271331Z
finishedDate : 2022-02-12T00:46:22.6090285Z
url          : https://tdc1tfsapp01.dayforce.com/tfs/DefaultCollection/d85566a3-9e95-4891-9fd8-42750a0bc250/_apis/pipelines/8781/runs/1399783
resources    : @{repositories=}
id           : 1399783
name         : 20220211.2



C:\>
```

Does it mean the variables are only available in Azure DevOps Services?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the API "[Runs - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)" to get the build.

Normally, in the response body of this API, you will see the pipeline variables are listed in the **`variables`** object.

[image]

Comment: Please, see **EDIT 1**